# Execution Patter of Multi-Threaded Server on Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, server

I like to know what should be the execution pattern of Multiple Threads of a Server to implement TCP in request-response cycle of hi-performance Server (like dozens of packets with single or no system call on Linux using Packet MMAP or some other way).

Design 1) For simplicity, Start two thread in main at the start of a Server program. one thread just getting packets directly from network interface(s) like wlan0/eth0. and once number of packets read in one cycle (using while loop with poll() in Linux). wake up the other thread using conditional variable signal call. and after waking up, other thread (sender) process and send packet as tcp response.

Design 2) Start receiver thread at the start of main program. The packet receiver thread reads packets from interfaces using while loop and poll(). When number of packets received, create sender thread and pass number of packets received in one cycle  to sender as parameter. Sender thread process the packets and respond as tcp response.

(I think, Design 2 will be more easy to implement but is there any design issue or possible performance issue with this approach this is the question). Since creating buffer to pass to sender thread from receiver thread need to be allocated prior to receiving packets. So I know the size of buffer to allocate. Also in this execution pattern I am creating new thread (which will return and end execution after processing packets and responding tcp response). I like to know what will be the performance issue with this approach since I am creating new thread every time I get a batch of packet from interfaces.

In first approach I am not creating more than two threads (or limited number of threads and threads can be tracked easily for logging and debugging since I will know how many thread are initially created) In second approach I don't know how many threads are hanging around and executing concurrently.

I need any advise how real website like youtube/ or others may have handled this in there hi-performance server if they had followed this way of implementing their front facing servers.

Answer (score 0):

First when going to a 'real' website the magic lies in having a load balancers and a whole bunch of worker nodes to take the load and you easily exceed the boundary of a single system. For example take a look at the following AWS reference architecture for serving web pages at scale [AWS Cloud Architecture for serving web whitepaper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/web-application-hosting-best-practices/an-aws-cloud-architecture-for-web-hosting.html).

That being said taking this one level down it is always interesting to look at how other well-known products have solved this issue. For example NGINX has an excellent [infographic](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/infographic-inside-nginx/) available and matching [blogpost](https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/) describing their architecture and threading.